# Cloudera CDH4 install fails using Yum

Tags: hadoop, installation, yum, cloudera

I am trying to install the datanode and it gives the error "metadata file does not match checksum"
I am behind a proxy

I have tried everything- yum clear all, yum clear metadata. I also edited the yum conf and disabled caching.
In addition, i also manually deleted the cache directory. Nothing works. Nothing. Please help.
On another machine, i was able to get the name node successfully installed

```
**[root@bi ~]# export http_proxy=   myproxy**               

**[root@bi ~]# sudo yum install hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker hadoop-hdfs-datanode**
```

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/redhat/5/x86_64/cdh/4/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match    checksum
Trying other mirror.
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/redhat/5/x86_64/cdh/4/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match  checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/primary.xml.gz from cloudera-cdh4: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try

Comment: Try `yum clean dbcache` and then `yum update yum`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, there seams to be a problem with proxy. Try an other proxy or take a look at your configures there.

Answer (score 0):

cloudera manager creates a .repo before installing, and if there are any conflicts it causes that error.

To avoid such conflicts,

1)Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/cloudera-manager.repo file using any stable version of cloudera manager.(5.2.1 was the version when I did this)

My cloudera-manager.repo file looked like this:

```
[cloudera-manager]
name = Cloudera Manager, Version 5.2.1
baseurl = http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5.2.1/
gpgkey = http://archive.cloudera.com/redhat/cdh/RPM-GPG-KEY-cloudera
gpgcheck = 1
```

2) Now run the following command to make the installer use the local repo file.

```
./cloudera-manager-installer.bin --skip_repo_package=1
```